# Spring batch vtd-xml

Tags: xml, spring, xpath, spring-batch, vtd-xml

Scenario is like i have huge xml file coming in as an input, xml file may contain only one node or it might contain multiple nodes. I have written my Custom reader which extends AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader, over ridden the doOpen() and doRead() accordingly. I have used vtd-xml for unmarshalling. Problem is even my xml file contain only one node doRead() method is getting called multiple times. ideally after evaluating xpath value it should come out of the loop. Please suggest me where i am doing wrong.

Comment: you are not giving enough details on your problem? what do you mean by one node or multiple nodes?

Comment: <Trns>
  <Ref>
   <InstrId>12345678901</InstrId> 
   <EndToEndId>1234567893</EndToEndId> 
   <TxId>12345678</TxId> 
  </Ref>
  <Code> 
   <TxCd>
    <Domn>
  
               <Cd>BOOK</Cd>
     <Fmly>
      <Cd>STLM</Cd>
      <SubFmlyCd>DSTL</SubFmlyCd>
     </Fmly>
    </Domn>
    <Issr>1</Issr>
        <TxCD>
      </Code>
<Trns>

Comment: This is sample xml file. I can have a single <Trns></Trns> or multiple  <Trns></Trns> in input file.  Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: Having multiple Trns makes it an invalid XML. According to XML spec, you can *only* have one root element per xml file.

Comment: Can you please update your question with examples of your XML and the code you're using.

Comment: Hi Michael thanks a lot for the reply. But it was my fault that i was not moving the autoPilot to the parent node properly. Everything is working fine only thing is i have to test the performance.

Comment: Regarding performance, I wrote a blog a while back and here is the URL that might help you https://ximpleware.wordpress.com/2015/10/12/performance-tuning/

Comment: @vtd-xml-author i had gone through the blog and measured the performance. I am getting the more time in VTD. It is a complex structured  xml and i am using xpath frequently(Not using xpath in loop). This might hit the performance? Please suggest...

Comment: Did you set the location cache depth to 5? how big is your document? Can you send me a test case so I can offer further suggestions.

Comment: @vtd-xml-author  my apologies for late reply... It's 3.4Gb xml file... As i told i am using xpath frequently to get only the required attributes i want to pick from xml... Kindly suggest to improve the performance..

Comment: you must be using extended vtd-xml on 64-bit jvm right? is 3.4GB a single XML?

Comment: @vtd-xml-author Yes it is a 64-Bit jvm and it is a single file of size 3.4Gb.

Comment: so are you using extended vtd-xml?

Comment: @vtd-xml-author Yes i am.

Comment: did you read the code examples in http://vtd-xml.sourceforge.net/codeSample/cs12.html

Comment: @vtd-xml-author Yes i have red code example, and used MEM_MAPPED, only difference is i am applying xpath for individual attributes

Comment: What is the problem you are experiencing? What does your xpath look like?

Comment: @vtd-xml-author Performance issue... VTD is performing slower when compared to Stax parsing.. Suppose i have a firstName attribute in one of the child nodes my xpath looks like p.selectXPath("./n:name/text()") where n is the namespace and i made my pilot pointing to the current node

Comment: Can you post your code? What is the setting ie.JVM heap size etc? Please provide as much info as you can.

Comment: Can't help you if no further info is provided...